# React ref to pass through child rendered as this.props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple React component that wraps another and provides some resizing ability.

I'm having trouble getting a ref to the single child passed to Resizer. There doesnt seem to be an elegant way to ask React for a ref to a pass through child, even when assuming `this.props.children` is a single node.

Any ideas?

**Usage**

```html
<Resizer>
  <MyColumn />
</Resizer>
<MyBody />
```

**Resizer.js**

```js
...
render() {
  return ([
    this.props.children,  // <== I need a ref to this component's DOM node
    <div className="resizer--class"></div>
  ])
}
```

**Caveats:**

- I dont want to force consumers to pass node refs to `<Resizer>`
- I dont want to wrap `<MyColumn />` in an extra `<div>`

  - This works, but alters the HTML structure:

    > `<div ref={this.assignChildRef}>{this.props.children}</div>`
- I dont want to store any state in flux
- I dont want to use a DOM workaround like [`node.previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) even though this technically would get me the child node

Comment: You can use `ReactDOM.findDomNode(this.props.children[0])` once the pass through component has mounted ([source](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode)).

Comment: @FK82 - `props.children` are React *elements*. `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` accepts a React *component* as its argument, with which it will find the DOM node in the actual DOM for that Component.

Comment: Right. There's a trick with `React.cloneElement` in [this issue thread](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4244) which might be what you need.